# I'm writing a program to pass a variable to a function that adds terms to a library and I'm getting a KeyError in python

Tags: python, dictionary

```
if userChoice == 3:
    term = input("What term do you wish to add: ")
    dictionary_insert(term)
```

This is the code that calls the function into play.

```
def dictionary_insert(w):
    #code
    term = acronyms[w]
    if term not in acronyms:
        definition = input("\nWhat's the definition?: ")
        acronyms[term] = definition
        print("\n", term, "has been added.")
    else:
        print("\nThat term already exits!")
    return(w)
```

This is the function itself.  I don't know why i get a key error when I do this.  Did I not pass a variable correctly?

Comment: You are using `if` condition **before** the command `term = acronyms[w]` this is the thing which is giving rise to error.

Comment: Alright, so what kind of loop should I use?  I'm not sure how to test if the term is not in the library any other way.

Comment: Also a tip: Use `.get()` wherever necessary while accessing the value for a specific key, This is due to the reason that, you can specify default value in case the key is not found in the dictionary and you will not get instead .. like `sample_dict.get("anmol", -1)`, this -1 would be the default value returned if the key is not found,

Comment: I hope the answers worked for you, tell if you face any problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a KeyError because when you try to insert a new term into your dictionary, the line `term = acronyms[w]` is executed first, and that will result in a KeyError because there is no term with key `w`. You need to remove that line; or move it to within the if condition.

Comment: I thought I had to add term to the the acronyms dictionary before I could define it.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You don't need to - If you just do `dictionary[new_item] = "new_definition"`, this will add a new item:definition pair to your dictionary. No need to have a special line just for that.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a key error because in line 3 of your functions, you are assigning `term` to `acronyms[w]` and `w` isn't always in `acronyms`

```
def dictionary_insert(w):
    if w in acronyms:
        term = acronyms[w]
        acronyms[term] = input("\nWhat's the definition?: ")
        print("\n", term, "has been added.")
    else:
        print("\nThat term already exits!")
    return w
```

I moved the assignment of `term` inside the if statement so that `acronyms[w]` is only called once we know that it won't cause a key error.

**NOTES:**

1. Why are you returning `w`? There doesn't seem to be any point since it isn't modified by the function. You're just returning the input.*
2. Why are you assigning term to `acronyms[w]`. That assignment is to the value, not the key, and you are using definitions as values.

```py
def dictionary_insert(w):
    acronyms[w] = acronyms.get(w) if w in acronyms else input("\nWhat's the definition?: ")
```

I removed the print statements in the above version of your function, but other than that it preforms identically to the larger version at the beginning of my answer.